# Upgrade to PHP 7 - no package php70w available

Tags: php, centos, upgrade

I try to update my godaddy VPS with cpanel and Centos 6 to use PHP7.

As easyApache isn't supporting PHP7 yet, I have to do it through SSH.

So i did the following:

```
yum update

rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm

rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm

yum install php70w
```

But after the last step I am getting the error message:

```
No package php70w available.
```

What am I doing wrong, no matter what tutorial I look at - I always fail at this step: yum install php70w

Comment: I don't generally use Centos myself, but I did install it once, and there was an `--enablerepo=webtatic` (or enable it in /etc/yum.repos.d/webtatic.repo) mentioned.

Comment: With new cPanel version there is EasyApache4 and php7 is available in Easyapache4. You need to configure EasyApache4 to use php7